# How do I execute a function on a page after navigating to it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a CupertinoDialogAction button in Flutter that navigates back to a page with a timer. I want to start the timer function of that page upon clicking the button. Is this possible?

Here is the current code that I have to create the dialog action and navigate to the timer page upon being clicked.

[Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heskg.png)

Comment: Please share your code directly on StackOverflow. Screenshots of code are really not helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Create an init state method on the page with the timer and call your function there - this runs when the page is initialised

```dart
class TimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimerPageState createState() => _TimerPageState();
}

class _TimerPageState extends State<TimerPage> {

 .
 .
 .

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startTimer();
  }

 .
 .
 .

}
```

As said in the comments, add your code in the body of your question - this will allow us to give a more complete answer.